# Difference beween TAM 5.1 and TAM 6?

Tags: tivoli-identity-manager

I'm working with both TAM 5.1 and TAM 6.
But I couln't find any difference between these both versions, except for the two step login in TAM 6.

Can you tell me what is the basic difference between these two version TAM 5.1 and TAM6 ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if my answer is obvious but have you referred the release info? 
Link here - [TAM 6 Release notes](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v2r1/topic/com.ibm.itame.doc_6.0/relnotes03.htm)

Now I haven't worked with 5.1 but apparently there are some major differences. I've listed a few below.

Base

- 64 bit support for some windows, RHEL and SUSE OSes.

WebSEAL

- EAI support
- Maintaining session state using HTTP headers
- Multidomain AD user Id support in SPNEGO
- LTPA V2 support
- Junction throttling
- IPV6, VirtualHost junctions
- Session management support via SMS for multiple WebSeal instances  -

It's similar for the TAM plugin used in webservers if you don't like WebSEAL

P.S. now in the next verision i.e. TAM 6.1 if I recall correctly it allows you to add the HTTPOnly flag in the cookie which is a critical security feature which TAM 6.0 lacks.